# Issue with Windows Scheduler

Tags: vbscript, outlook, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I am attempting to run a *.vbs script (below) using Windows Scheduler without success. From what I can see it is a basic script which aims to send an email. When this is run manually, it is working perfectly. Why will this not work with Windows Scheduler? The tasks starts and ends without any issues but without email being sent.

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With outMail
    .to = "test@test.com"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Test - " 
    .Recipients.ResolveAll
    .Send
End With

Set outMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

XML for Task

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2017-09-08T14:08:04.8746028</Date>
    <Author>JOLLYES2\Kajan</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <TimeTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2017-09-08T14:10:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </TimeTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>JOLLYES2\Kajan</UserId>
      <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>false</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\WTD\WTD_Test.vbs</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Answer (score 0):

Task Scheduler runs as a service - no Office app (Outlook included) can be used from a service. Especially if another instance of Outlook is already running - Outlook is a singleton, so when your scripts connects to the already running instance of Outlook, COM system refuses to marshal calls between two processes running in different security contexts.